# IMG doesn't respect container's padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already have a solution for this, which is to set the `IMG` width to `90%`. It doesn't make sense to me that's why I want to understand why it is so.

[Screenshot from Google Chrome 46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ7ZQ.png)

The container is a floating `DIV` with `15px` padding on both sides and a width set to `100%`, and the contained `IMG` has `12px` margin on both sides with its width set to `100px`. It seems to be filling out the grandparent instead of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

By default, CSS margin and padding is not included in the width. In other words, if you set something to width 100%, it's width will be the full width of the container and then the padding and margin get added to it.

Bootstrap and other CSS packages change the CSS default so that it will likely achieve what you are trying to do. That property is:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Granted * might be a bit too broad, but basically anything you apply that to will cause the width to be more flexible when you are working with paddings and margins inside of percentage-based containers.

Rather than apply a margin to the image that is 100%, I'd recommend using the padding of the outer container and remove the margin from the image.

Comment: I think that's a better solution than using `90%` on the `width`. Thanks!